# Jenkins Ingress with k8s v1.19

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I had a Jenkins values.yaml file written prior to v1.19, I need some help to change it to be v1.19 compliant.

In the old `Values.yaml` below, I tried adding `http path:/`. Should the `pathType` be `ImplementationSpecific`?

Only `defaultBackend` works for some reason, not sure what I'm doing wrong with `path` and `pathType`.

```
ingress:
enabled: true
# Override for the default paths that map requests to the backend
paths:
  # - backend:
  #     serviceName: ssl-redirect
  #     servicePort: use-annotation
  - backend:
      serviceName: >-
        {{ template "jenkins.fullname" . }}
      # Don't use string here, use only integer value!
      servicePort: 8080
# For Kubernetes v1.14+, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
labels: {}
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: jenkins-sandbox-blah
  networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: jenkins-sandbox-blah
  kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"

# kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
# kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
# Set this path to jenkinsUriPrefix above or use annotations to rewrite path
# path: "/jenkins"
# configures the hostname e.g. jenkins.example.com
hostName: jenkins.sandbox.io
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several changes to the definition of Ingress resources between  `v1.18` and `v1.19`.

In `v1.18`, we defined paths like this (see: [A minimal Ingress resource example](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource)):

```
  paths:
  - path: /testpath
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
      serviceName: test
      servicePort: 80
```

In version `1.19` it was changed to: (see: [A minimal Ingress resource example](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource)):

```
  paths:
  - path: /testpath
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
      service:
        name: test
        port:
          number: 80
```

In your example, you can slightly modified the `values.yaml` and try again:
**NOTE:** You may need to change the port number and [pathType](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) depending on your configuration. Additionally, I've added the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation because I'm using [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and I didn't configure the hostname.

```
$ cat values.yaml
controller:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    paths:
    - path: "/"
      pathType: Prefix
      backend:
        service:
          name: >-
            {{ template "jenkins.fullname" . }}
          port:
            number: 8080
    apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: jenkins-sandbox-blah
      networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: jenkins-sandbox-blah
      kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # configures the hostname e.g. jenkins.example.com
    # hostName: jenkins.sandbox.io
```

Comment: The last one worked with no "pathType" set